# MATLAB Radio Buttons: How to choose only one at a time

Tags: matlab, user-interface, radio-button

I'm trying to get MATLAB buttons to work. I have multiple radio buttons now. But when I tried to choose multiple buttons to test out the GUI. Weirdly, the radio buttons acts like a checkbox. How do I change the codes so that I only can choose 1 radio button at one time?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you build it, but you can include the buttons inside a `buttongroup`, as described here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uibuttongroup.html

There is also a code example for that.